Machine learning from multiple time series
I have a set of 192 sensors. One measure needs 4 sensors to measure (say it's average temperature between sensors used, in a complex material). Those sensors are distributed with a specific pattern to get info from the whole material.
So I have about 10k combinations of those 192 sensors say something like
1,2,3,4, val_1
2,3,4,5, val_2,
....
13,10,1,192, val_x.

There is some relation between val_1 and val_2, since they use 3 common sensors that refers to roughly similar space. Some for all other combinations, there is a complex relation between all val_.
Now, imagine that all values where collected the same time. This is my dataset1.
I repeat this measure cycle 2k times (say like a time series), collecting accordingly dataset2, dataset3, ...datasetn.
The way val_1 is changing over time is related also the way val_2 is changing over time.
In other words, val_1 and val_2 are related both in space and time.
What I look for is for a ML algorithm, that it will be trained from those 2k time datasets, find a relation between the 10k combinations, so future measures will only use a subset of the 10k combinations (say data compression).
What kind of ML algorithm can work ?
